# How to find out how much statistical difference is there between the two groups in mann whiney U test?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, nonparametric

So, i applied mann whitney U test to find out the difference in salary between two groups( eg- gender - male and female). There is indeed a statistical difference between the groups.

**Result of Mann Whitney U test:**

`WilcoxonMannWhitneyResult(alternative='two.sided', statistic=-13.689596321778781, HodgesLehmann=-8805178.0, lowerCI=-10482000.0, upperCI=-7305168.0, pvalue=1.1715832236246678e-42)`

I want to find out how much difference is in the salary of a particular person due to the gender. In other words, how much more a woman would make if she were a man in this dataset. Is there a way to how i can find that out ?

Comment: (1) Make a reasonable estimate of male salaries. (2) Ditto for female salaries. (3) Subtract.

Comment: If i take mean salaries of both gender and then take difference of them, would that be okay ??

Comment: Sure, but then why not use a suitable test for means in the first place? Personally, with things like salaries I think the interesting questions are nearer to percentage ones (differences in salaries will tend to be smaller when salaries are small, for example, since there's less "room to move"; salaries won't be negative). So I'd probably be looking to measure in percentage terms myself.